Replacing a 40 yr old hard wired drop in stove with freestanding range
We removed a drop in stove. The wiring appears to be 2, #8 (or #6) braided wires wrapped with a braided neutral/ground. Do I need to upgrade the wiring? I plan to install a new gangbox with a 3 prong 40 amp plug outlet? The existing wire label appears to be labeled as Type SZ cable Style C Type ERHW CDRS. Any help would be appreciated. The new stove is a GE GRS500 PV SS.

You probably do not need to upgrade the the wiring if the stoves use the same amps, 40 to 40.  3 prong is an old unsafe type of circuit that was ban in 96, but grandfather in to keep.  It is highly recommended to upgrade it to newer 4 prong circuit, two hots, a neutral and the usually missing ground to save you if there is a electrical problem.  Can read up on NEMA 10 type circuits.

What's the new model # ?

GE GRS500 PV SS  Brand New

The manual allows 3-wire installation.  Whether your cable qualifies for three-wire with bare braided neutral may be answered here, or if it remains unclear should be a new question with photos.  Whether grandfathering applies is really up to you.  Nobody else is going to interpret the undocumented history of exactly how that cable was terminated and when.  If there's an unfinished basement ceiling below, I'd run a new 6/3 cable and put in a 50A socket on a 40A breaker.  You're here asking, you should be amenable to the idea.

3 prong 40 amp plug outlet ???? That is perfectly fine in the unlikely case of a 240V-only stove. If, as is common with US appliances, it is actually 240V/120V then in a modern installation (and if you didn't have a receptacle there before then this is a new installation) it MUST use a 4-wire connection and, if connected via cord/plug, a 4-wire receptacle (NEMA 14 instead of NEMA 10 (obsolete, not allowed for new installations, no ground) or NEMA 6 (240V only, no neutral)).
Now that we know this is a GE GRS500 PV SS, the GE installation instructions, we know this is a 240V/120V neutral required appliance. The instructions document both plug/cord and hardwired (they call it conduit, I'll explain more below) connections and both 3-wire (neutral/ground bonded in the appliance) and 4-wire (separate neutral and ground wires) installations. Which gives you 4 options, which I'll list in order of my personal preference:

4-wire hardwired - This removes the receptacle from the equation. Since the receptacle ends up hidden behind the stove, it isn't even that useful as a way to provide a disconnect for servicing since you have to pull the stove out to get to it. But that does mean you have to flip the breaker for any servicing - not normally a big deal. This requires replacing your existing cable/wires. 100% safe.
4-wire plug/cord/receptacle - This provides a full modern connection. You attach a 4-wire cord/plug to the stove and install a 4-wire NEMA 14-50 receptacle and run new cable/wire. 100% safe, but one extra point of failure.
3-wire hardwired - Assuming your existing cable is suitable for 40A, this is acceptable as it is a direct use of the existing configuration. But it requires a neutral-ground bond on the appliance and therefore is not as safe in certain situations as a 4-wire installation. But it avoids having to run new cable/wires.
3-wire plug/cord/receptacle - While the instructions allow this (except in: new construction, mobile homes, RVs and where local codes prohibit it), I would argue that it should not be allowed in your situation as you are installing a new receptacle. A new receptacle means you didn't have a receptacle there before, which means this is a significant change to the circuit and therefore the new rules - 4-wire with ground - should apply. Otherwise the same advantages (no new cable/wires) and disadvantages (safety) as a 3-wire hardwired installation.

Note that the manual refers to "conduit" as the alternative to plug/cord. I suspect that is to avoid someone trying to connect Romex or similar cable directly to the stove. Doing so would not be as safe because (a) non-metallic cable doesn't handle heat as well as wires in conduit and (b) while not moved frequently, the last few feet of wire do get moved when the stove is moved for servicing. Which means you typically install either cable or wires in conduit (metal or PVC) from the breaker to a junction box and then some sort of flexible conduit or armored cable from the junction box to the stove.

GE GRS500 PV SS Brand New
